# I cant understand this block of code

Tags: java, morphia

I will learn Java and Morphia. I have this block of code:

```
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Embedded;
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Id;
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Property;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

@Entity
public class Hotel {

    @Id private ObjectId id;

    private String name;
    private int stars;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;
...
}
```

could please tell me what does `@Entity`, `@Id`, `@Embedded` mean? and generralz when should I use @ in Java
Thank you so much

Comment: Google about "java annotations"

Comment: Want to learn Morphia ? Read Morphia doc.

Comment: don't you have google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/):

> Annotations, a form of metadata, provide data about a program that is not part of the program itself. Annotations have no direct effect on the operation of the code they annotate.
>
> Annotations have a number of uses, among them:
>
> 1. Information for the compiler — Annotations can be used by the compiler to detect errors or suppress warnings.
> 2. Compile-time and deployment-time processing — Software tools can process annotation
> 3. information to generate code, XML files, and so forth.
>    Runtime processing — Some annotations are available to be examined at runtime.

You can get the list of [all annotation in Morphia](https://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/AllAnnotations):

[Id](https://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/AllAnnotations#Id) : Marks a field in an @Entity to be the "id" field in mongodb.

[Entity](https://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/AllAnnotations#Entity) : Marks entities to be stored directly in a collection.

[Embedded](https://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/AllAnnotations#Embedded) : Allows customization of certain options.

Answer (score 3):

@ is used for annotations. When you use @ tag above any class, method or parameter this means you apply some rules on that which is resolved by some resolver.

To learn annotation see links:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation
2. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/

Annotations, a form of metadata, provide data about a program that is not part of the program itself. Annotations have no direct effect on the operation of the code they annotate.

Annotations have a number of uses, among them:

**Information for the compiler** — Annotations can be used by the compiler to detect errors or suppress warnings.

**Compile-time and deployment-time processing** — Software tools can process annotation information to generate code, XML files, and so forth.

**Runtime processing** — Some annotations are available to be examined at runtime.

To read morphai annotaion read this link:
https://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/AllAnnotations

Form above documentation:
**@Entity**: Marks entities to be stored directly in a collection.  [examples](https://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/EntityAnnotation) 
**@Id**: Marks a field in an @Entity to be the "id" field in mongodb. 
**@Embedded**: Allows customization of certain options. [examples](https://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/EmbeddedAnnotation)

Answer (score 2):

These are [annotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation), they're rendered at compile time (although their values can be checked at runtime).  They were added into Java version 1.5.

The annotations specifically in this question relate to Morphia which is a [Mongodb library](https://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/QuickStart)

Answer (score 2):

```
@Entity, @Id, @Embedded
```

those are called as [annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) in java.

> Annotations, a form of metadata, provide data about a program that is not part of the program itself. Annotations have no direct effect on the operation of the code they annotate.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, morphia has moved to github at https://github.com/mongodb/morphia.  I'll update the docs on googlecode to point to the new home.